# Creating a composite key in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

I've got a conjoining table, which I need to insert into with LINQ. But I can't insert into it because it has no primary key. I created a "Unique Key" which is a composite in the VS2010 table designer, but LINQ still won't accept it. How can I create a composite primary key so that I can insert into this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2);
```

Or in the designer hold down control when selecting the columns before the right click.

Comment: Control-selecting them and selecting primary key worked like a charm, thanks!